# Question on Variable Transformation in Coordinate Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry

I am self-studying Riley's Math Methods book and I am a little confused about a solution provided  for one question. I've provided the question and the solution below (I'm confused about d) only), but I'm hoping someone can walk me through the transformation from x and y to the lines x+y=0 and x-y=0.

In terms of the transformation, I tried to think of it by analogy to the standard y=x^2 case. To me it seems like the x-y=0 (y=x) line should be taking the role of the y-axis, while the x+y=0 (y=-x) line takes the role of the x-axis. And yet clearly, the opposite is true, as the parabola is symmetric about y=-x.
Am I misunderstanding somehow (obviously I am!)?

[Desmos Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MADVY.png)

[Problem Statement, see d) only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C5eo.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr1LI.png)

Comment: Please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of posting pictures of them, especially as you don’t have enough rep yet to put the pictures inline. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick reference on formatting mathematical expressions using MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s one way to think about it that might help you keep things sorted out. In the standard coordinate system, the $x$-coordinate measures the (signed) distance from the $y$-axis and vice-versa. Now recall that the formula for the signed distance from the line $ax+by+c=0$ to an arbitrary point is ${ax+by+c\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$. So, when you transform an equation to some other rectangular coordinate system, you replace $x$ with an expression for the new $y$-axis, and vice-versa.

Taking your specific example, then, in the standard equation $Y=X^2$, the left-hand side is the distance from the line $Y=0$, which is the $X$-axis, and the right-hand side is the square of the distance from the line $X=0$, the $Y$-axis. The line of symmetry is the latter. Rewriting the fourth equation as $$(x+y)^2=8(x-y)$$ and comparing to the standard equation, we can see that the line $x-y=0$ corresponds to $Y=0$, i.e., the $X$-axis, while $x+y=0$ corresponds to the $Y$-axis, which is the parabola’s line of symmetry.

Incidentally, all of these conics can be classified by examining the determinants of certain matrices related to the equations. In particular, the basic type of conic represented by $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ can be determined by examining the sign of $B^2-4AC$, the *discriminant* of the equation. You also need to check for degeneracy by seeing if a $3\times3$ determinant vanishes, which is the case for the third conic, which is a degenerate hyperbola—a pair of intersecting lines.

Comment: Thank you! Totally makes sense. Just BTW, it seems like you mixed up Y-axis and X-axis just before the equation of the parabola. Other than that this clarifies beautifully!

Comment: @1729_SR Good catch! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You understand how the initial equation has been rewritten as $(x+y)^2 = 8(x-y)$, do you ?

After that point, your analogy is basically correct and useful. The author shows that the two lines $x+y=0$ and $x-y=0$ are orthogonal (are you OK with that?) so they can be considered an orthogonal frame. Since we are using $x$ and $y$ already, the author introduces two other names : $u = x+y, v=x-y$. We get :
$u^2 = 8v$ which can be written as $u^2=4\times 2(x-y)$, which in the new $(u,v)$ frame is the equivalent of your $y = x^2$, with $u$ taking the place of $x+y$ and $v$ that of $x-y$.

Finally, your parabola $y=x^2$ is symmetric about $x=0$ : similarly, the parabola in the problem is symmetric about $u=0$, hence about $x+y=0$. QED...